# Hibernate CascadeType.Persist creates a select query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, cascade, hibernate-cascade

I am trying to persist an object which has one to many relation with other entity. Using **CascadeType.ALL** works but, indeed I do not want to delete that entity when I delete main object. Therefore I tried to use **CascadeType.PERSIST**. But when I use it it makes a select query and says that entity not found. So why hibernate does it when I use cascadeType.PERSIST.

Here is my class basically:

```
public class Employeer{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "employer_details", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employeer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "details_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private Set<Address> otherObjects= new HashSet<>();

}
```

So the question is why using **CascadeType.PERSIST**, does not persist Address element and creates a select query and says that entity not found. Why I want to use it, I do not want to delete entity from address table when I delete employeer.

Note: I was looking at this post. [Unable find Entity .. while trying to save data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47994519/unable-find-entity-while-trying-to-save-data) . But there I am trying to get why **CascadeType.PERSIST** does not work.

Comment: Ques. 1 why using CascadeType.PERSIST, does not persist Address element?
Ans. 1 It should work - please check are you setting address into Employee.

Comment: Yes I do set it. But as I said it generates select query into adress table before inserting. And as there is not this record in adress  table, it says that entity not found.